# ant build gives package does not exist error

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I am using ant build function on linux to compile a java program. I have three java files and I'm trying to import them to my main.java file but I get an error saying

```
/home/ggaz1/Ser321/Assigns/Assign2/src/main.java:4 error: package Assign2.src does not exist
```

here is the build.xml file. the path to it is

```
/home/ggaz1/Ser321/Assigns/Assign2

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Movie Library."
         default="targets" basedir="."
         xmlns:dn="antlib:org.apache.ant.dotnet"
         xmlns="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant"
         xmlns:cpptasks="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib.cpptasks">

   <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
   <property name="build" value="classes"/>
   <property environment="env"/>
   <property name="user" value="${env.USERNAME}"/>

   <target name="targets">
      <echo message="Targets are clean, prepare, build, execute, and targets"/>
   </target>

   <path id="compile.classpath">
      <pathelement location="${build}"/>
   </path>

   <target name="prepare">
      <mkdir dir="${build}" />
   </target>

   <target name="clean">
      <delete dir="${build}" failonerror="false"/>
   </target>

   <target name="build" depends="prepare">
      <javac srcdir="${src.dir}"
             includeantruntime="false"
             destdir="${build}">
        <src path="src"/>
         <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
      </javac>
   </target>

   <target name="execute.java" depends="build"
           description="Run the program">
         <echo message="command line execute: java -cp classes main, MovieDescription, MovieLibrary" />
         <java classname="main" fork="yes">
           <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
         </java>
   </target>
</project>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the full error message (by editing the question not in a comment) and the target which failed. What is your Java file layout? Is your main class at the root of the classpath? And is there a subdirectory  `Assign2` containing the class `MovieDescription`?

Comment: I have the folder as Assign2 which then has a src folder with MovieDescription.java, MovieLibrary.java and main.java.

i corrected the question and added the error

Comment: You should show us the relevant part of your build.xml. The target that fails and associated properties. If your build.xml isn't too long, you can include the whole file. And don't forget to mention the path to the build.xml. Without that information it is impossible to help.

Comment: I went ahead and added the build.xml file along with its path. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have any packages. All your Java source code files are located in the src folder. The src folder is the root of your packages. If you want a package `assign2` you have to create a folder in src called `assign2` and you should place all Java files which belong to the `assign2` package into that folder.

Assuming your `Main` class itself is without a package and your classes `MovieDescription` and `MovieLibrary` are in package `assign2`.

Then your file layout should look like:

```
--src
   |
   +---- Main.java
   |
   +---- assign2
            |
            +---- MovieDescription.java
            |
            +---- MovieLibrary.java
```

Then `Main.java` doesn't have any package declarartion.

Im `MovieDescription.java` and `MovieLibrary.java` the package declaration should be:

```
package assign2;
[...]
```

And the imports in `Main.java` look like:

```
import assign2.MovieLibrary;
import assign2.MovieDescription;
```

Maybe you should have a look at the [Oracle Java Tutorial, Lesson: Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html).

And according to the Java naming conventions you should use only names starting with lower case letters for packages and variables. Classes should start always with an upper case letter.